# Problem using Linkedin API

Tags: php, json, api, linkedin-api

I am using linkedin api to get info about the logged in user. I am able to get firstname and lastname, picture etc., It works fine. But I am not able to get recommendations. I am able to get number of recommenders using **num-recommenders**.

I am not getting `**recommendations-received**` according to http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1061. I printed out the json response no recommendations Object for the user.

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For unfortunate reasons, if you want to get access to that field, you need to replace IN.API.Profile().fields("firstName","lastName","recommendationsReceived") with IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(first-name,last-name,recommendations-received)").

This is a good thread to read on the LinkedIn Developer forums: http://developer.linkedin.com/message/8805